# C# public partial struct methods for more System.Windows.Media.Color

Tags: c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, colors, struct, public-method

How can I put in additional methods for manipulating color ?
Best would be to overload  the struct System.Windows.Media.Color.
It is **NOT** a class (in c#).

Now i'm tinkering with putting (in the same file for testing or must i put it in a
different file) an namespace (Silverlight Application36 or System.Windows.Media ?)
and a partial struct Color Normalize (double R, ...).

I should see MyColor.Normalize() start being recognized by intellisense ?

I'm not.  I'm looking to put in a suite of overloaded color manipulations using
floating and double numbers instead of unsigned byte integers.

Any hints while I wack at it ?

Cheers!

dr.K

Answer (score 3):

Just use [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx):

```
public static class ColorExtensions
{
    public static Color Normalize(this Color)
    {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

It's fine if its a struct.

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample windows forms app and put in a .cs file:

```
namespace System.Windows.Media
{
    public partial struct Color
    {
        public double Normalize(double r, double g, double b)
        {
            return r + g + b;
        }
    }
}
```

this causes the intellisense to show the Normalize method:

[image: partial struct color]

Comment: still tinkering... thanks for the pointers. Extension methods not partial classes seem to be the way to do this. will post answers.

Comment: nope, still tinkering. see other post on overloading MS Point struct.

Comment: still not happy. i don't want to have to wrap Color and color in MyColor